# Accessing collections data from Google+ API

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-apis-explorer

I'm using the Google Plus API, and there seems to be no information in the JSON response regarding the collection of the post. I was wondering if there was a way to access which collection a post belongs using the API data.

For example, could we use the URL given to parse the collection from the webpage? Does anyone have any idea how this could be done in a performant way?

Answer (score 0):

The google+ api is a read only api and every limited it gives you access to people, activities and comments.

Activites list returns a list of all [activities#resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities#resource) posts by a user. [try it](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=me&collection=public&_h=1&)

The only collection you can send is public.   the response looks like this.

```
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "etag": "\"RKS4-q7QGL10FxltAebpjqjKQR0/82jivrLU7ubQ-fwlLaXGSt3krb8\"",
   "title": "",
   "published": "2018-06-18T07:03:54.034Z",
   "updated": "2018-06-18T07:03:54.034Z",
   "id": "z13lu3vowpa5x3aws04chl2brzavs1rplos0k",
   "url": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton/posts/STgianNMQwU",
   "actor": {
    "id": "117200475532672775346",
    "displayName": "Linda Lawton",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/117200475532672775346",
    "image": {
     "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg?sz=50"
    },
    "verification": {
     "adHocVerified": "UNKNOWN_VERIFICATION_STATUS"
    }
   },
   "verb": "post",
   "object": {
    "objectType": "note",
    "actor": {
     "verification": {
      "adHocVerified": "UNKNOWN_VERIFICATION_STATUS"
     }
    },
    "content": "",
    "url": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton/posts/STgianNMQwU",
        "replies": {
         "totalItems": 0,
         "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13lu3vowpa5x3aws04chl2brzavs1rplos0k/comments"
        },
        "plusoners": {
         "totalItems": 0,
         "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13lu3vowpa5x3aws04chl2brzavs1rplos0k/people/plusoners"
        },
        "resharers": {
         "totalItems": 0,
         "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13lu3vowpa5x3aws04chl2brzavs1rplos0k/people/resharers"
        },
        "attachments": [
         {
          "objectType": "article",
          "displayName": "leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples",
          "content": "AspNetCoreSecuritySamples - Samples for various ASP.NET Core Security Features",
          "url": "https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples",
          "image": {
           "url": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/1pdxjC-TsuF0-8yHOZKvfDOXG1pNWAIemDoW7OzrFy8pcckGqr0BTJj-TwgW9KgEuoGLJjfUKLWSCouJwTT7FjoOmZ_xURQwzz4=w506-h910",
           "type": "image/jpeg",
           "height": 910,
           "width": 506
          },
          "fullImage": {
           "url": "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/1454075?s=400&v=4",
           "type": "image/jpeg"
          }
         }
        ]
       },
       "provider": {
        "title": "Google+"
       },
       "access": {
        "kind": "plus#acl",
        "description": "Public",
        "items": [
         {
          "type": "public"
         }
        ]
       }
      },
```

the above post  [here](https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton/posts/STgianNMQwU) is actually within one of my collections.  But no were in the response does it mention the id of the collection that its in which is olLcVE

As i mentioned this is a very limited api and what you want to do is not available.